# Can you select a string resource with a name like

Tags: android, android-resources

I am thinking of creating a small dynamic layout using `strings.xml` as a base.
I know how to select single resources but is there a way of selecting ALL resources with a name like "Intro_"

A bit like a Select where like query.

So if i had some strings like;

```
Intro_Welcome
Intro_FirstParagraph
SecondScreen_Welcome
```

List of strings `mList = select all string resources with a name like "Intro_"`

`mList` would now contain the string of `Intro_Welcome` and `Intro_FirstParagraph`

Any help is usefull
Thank you

Comment: You can use an array defined in the string resource file. Probably the closest you can get to what you want. Just use `<string-array name="">`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this like you described. The string resources name that you define in your xml file are mapped into int values. So, when you use they in your code, you use by the int value created.

You may consider using a modified version of [this class](https://gist.github.com/brucetoo/48be42fa1387717547e2), that can get the string resource id within the string text.